# Read an XML file & fetch its tags with corresponding values through Azure logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

There is folder in a FTP server which contains multiple XML files. How do I read the XML files & get the tags with its corresponding values through Azure logic apps only(Logic apps may contain azure function in it as a step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created some xml files in my ftp folder, the xml format show as:

```
<id>1</id>
<name>hury</name>
```

Below is the screenshot of my logic app for your reference:
[image]

According to the screenshot, we need to create "Initialize variable" action to initialize a variable named "xmlstring". Then use "List files in folder" to access the xml files in your ftp folder.

After that, add "For each" action to loop the xml files from your ftp folder, and then use "Get file content" action and put the path in the File input box(shown as below)
[image]

Then create "Set variable" action to set the xml content to the variable(xmlstring) you created before(shown as below)
[image]

Next step please create "Parse JSON" action to parse the xmlstring, you can use "Use sample payload to generate schema" to generate the schema of the json(shown as below).
[image]

Now we can use the value in the xml in our logic app.
[image]

But for this solution, the prerequisite is all of your xml files have the same structure. Hope it would be helpful to you.

Comment: One more Query. Is there any way to read the XML file without parsing it to json format In logic app ?

Comment: Hi @SurajSahoo, as far as I know, we can just read XML file by parsing it to json. We can search connectors and actions with the keyword "xml" but can not find any action similar to the action for json(such as "Parse JSON" action).